# tqdm and numpy vectorize

Tags: python, numpy, tqdm

I am using a `np.vectorize`-ed function and would like to see the progress of the function with `tqdm`. However, I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

All the suggestions I have found relate to converting the calculation into a for-loop, or into a pd.DataFrame.

Comment: Why are  you using `np.vectorize`?

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Carl Kirstein's answer I came up with the following solution. I added the pbar element to `my_function` as an argument and updated it inside the function.

```py
with tqdm(total=len(my_inputs)) as pbar:
    my_output = np.vectorize(my_function)(my_inputs, pbar)
```

Somewhere inside `my_function` I added `pbar.update(1)`.

```py
def my_function(args, pbar):
    ...
    pbar.update(1)
    ...
```

Comment: Hi thanks, that is basically what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a method that works to get the tqdm progress bar to update with a np.vectorize function. I wrap the vectorize function using a with

```
with tqdm(total=len(my_inputs)) as pbar:
    my_output = np.vectorize(my_function)(my_inputs)
```

in my_function() I then add the following lines

```
global pbar
pbar.update(1)
```

and voila! I now have a progress bar that updates with each iteration. Only slight performance dip on my code.

Note: when you instantiate the function it might complain that pbar is not yet defined. Simply put a pbar = 0 before you instantiate, and then the function will call the pbar defined by the with

Hope it helps everyone reading here.

Comment: didn't work for me: ```progress_bar.update(1)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'update'```

Comment: my progress bar showed up, but it did not update itself. My `my_input` is a matrix. I used `total=my_input.size`

Comment: What worked for me was to add the pbar element to my function as an argument and update it inside the function. You can find more details in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge,`tqdm` does not wrap over `numpy.vectorize`.

To display the progress bar for numpy arrays, `numpy.ndenumerate` can be used.

Given the inputs and function:

```py
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = 2
def myfunc(a, b):
    "Return a-b if a>b, otherwise return a+b"
    if a > b:
        return a - b
    else:
        return a + b
```

Replace this vectorised part below

```py
# using numpy.vectorize
vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)
vfunc(a, b)
```

with this

```py
# using numpy.ndenumerate instead
[myfunc(x,b) for index, x in tqdm(np.ndenumerate(a))]
```

To see the `tqdm` progress.

Comment: Ah this is still just using a `for-loop` which I know how to do. I was hoping on getting `tqdm` to work with `np.vectorize`.  Additionally, I tried out your method, I noticed a significant time-difference. Is this because of the logging or because your method does not use `np.vectorize`? 

EG: `np_vectorized_sum timing: 0:00:00.005858` and `np_ndenumerate_sum timing:  0:00:02.856294` (sum over 100 by 100 mesh grid)

Comment: I think the difference is due to the use of SIMD in `np.vectorize`.